# Why is hibernate giving ConstraintException as if trying to create object when one already exists

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using saveOrUpdate() when updating/creating a CoverImage object. Very occasionally I'm getting a constraint violation on the primary key.

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: 
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_6 
ON PUBLIC.COVERIMAGE(DATAKEY)"; SQL statement:
```

It seems it is trying to create a new CoverImage (INSERT) instead of updating an existing CoverImage (UPDATE) but I don't know why because datakey is defined as the @id of the class and Im setting the datakey.

I use saveOrUpdate() rather than have separate save() and update() parts because the code is multithreaded. I actually check for the existence of the instance before calling this method and only call if the object doesn't exist so I don't expect it to already exist, but there is always the possibility as in the case. The problem seems to occur approximately about 1 in 3000 times.

Here is the Hibernate class

```
package com.jthink.songlayer;

import com.jthink.songlayer.utils.Base64Coder;
import org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReadParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *  An Image
 */
@Audited
@Entity
public class CoverImage
{

    public CoverImage()
    {

    }

    public CoverImage(byte[] imageData)
    {
        this.imageData=imageData;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String dataKey;

    @Version
    private int version;

    public String getDataKey()
    {
        return dataKey;
    }

    public void setDataKey(String dataKey)
    {
        this.dataKey = dataKey;
    }

    @Lob
    private byte[]  imageData;

    @Lob
    private byte[]  thumbnailData;

    private String  mimeType;
    private int     width;
    private int     height;
    private boolean isLinked;

    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_SOURCE")
    private String  source;

    @Lob
    private byte[]  resizedImageData;
    private int     resizedWidth;
    private int     resizedHeight;

    public byte[] getImageData()
    {
        return imageData;
    }

    public void setImageData(byte[] imageData)
    {
        this.imageData = imageData;
    }

    public byte[] getThumbnailData()
    {
        return thumbnailData;
    }

    public void setThumbnailData(byte[] thumbnailData)
    {
        this.thumbnailData = thumbnailData;
    }

    public String getMimeType()
    {
        return mimeType;
    }

    public void setMimeType(String mimeType)
    {
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
    }

    public int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width)
    {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height)
    {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public boolean isLinked()
    {
        return isLinked;
    }

    public void setLinked(boolean linked)
    {
        isLinked = linked;
    }


    public String getSource()
    {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public byte[] getResizedImageData()
    {
        return resizedImageData;
    }

    public void setResizedImageData(byte[] resizedImageData)
    {
        this.resizedImageData = resizedImageData;
    }

    public int getResizedWidth()
    {
        return resizedWidth;
    }

    public void setResizedWidth(int resizedWidth)
    {
        this.resizedWidth = resizedWidth;
    }

    public int getResizedHeight()
    {
        return resizedHeight;
    }

    public void setResizedHeight(int resizedHeight)
    {
        this.resizedHeight = resizedHeight;
    }

    /**
     * Create message digest of the byte data
     * <p/>
     * This uniquely identifies the imagedata, but takes up much less room than the original data
     *
     * @param imageData
     * @return
     */
    public static byte[] getImageDataDigest(byte[] imageData)
    {
        //Calculate checksum
        MessageDigest md;
        try
        {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae)
        {
            //This should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException(nsae);
        }

        md.reset();
        md.update(imageData);
        return md.digest();
    }

    public static String createKeyFromData(byte[] imageData)
    {
        try
        {
            String base64key = CharBuffer.wrap(Base64Coder.encode(getImageDataDigest(imageData))).toString();
            return base64key;
        }
        catch (NullPointerException npe)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create filename from sum");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code that uses it

```
   try
    {
        //Create thumbnail
        BufferedImage           thumb = ArtworkHelper.resizeToThumbnail(newBuffered, THUMBNAIL_SIZE);
        ByteArrayOutputStream   baos    = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(thumb, ImageFormats.V22_JPG_FORMAT.toLowerCase(), baos);
        session = com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Transaction tx  = session.beginTransaction();
        coverImage = new CoverImage(imageData);
        coverImage.setThumbnailData(baos.toByteArray());
        coverImage.setDataKey(CoverImage.createKeyFromData(imageData));
        coverImage.setSource(source);
        coverImage.setWidth(newBuffered.getWidth());
        coverImage.setHeight(newBuffered.getHeight());
        coverImage.setMimeType(ImageFormats.getMimeTypeForBinarySignature(imageData));
        session.saveOrUpdate(coverImage);
        tx.commit();
        return coverImage;
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed Creating Thumbnails" + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        return null;
    }
    catch(StaleObjectStateException sose)
    {
        return SongCache.findCoverImageBySourceInOwnSession(source);
    }
    finally
    {
        HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
    }
```

Full stack trace

```
10/01/2013 09.17.12:com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.DiscogsSongGroupMatcher:call:SEVERE: Failed AddSongToDatabase:Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_6 ON PUBLIC.COVERIMAGE(DATAKEY)"; SQL statement:
insert into CoverImage (height, imageData, isLinked, mimeType, resizedHeight, resizedImageData, resizedWidth, source, version, width, dataKey) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-166]
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_6 ON PUBLIC.COVERIMAGE(DATAKEY)"; SQL statement:
insert into CoverImage (height, imageData, isLinked, mimeType, resizedHeight, resizedImageData, resizedWidth, source, version, width, dataKey) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-166]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:128)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at $Proxy27.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2962)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3403)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1210)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:399)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
at com.jthink.songkong.db.SongCache.saveNewCoverImage(SongCache.java:332)
```

Comment: It's either something in your multithreading or how you generate the key (or both).  Post that code?

Comment: @Taylor The setDataKey() code is in the CoverImage class posted above, the exception occurs when i commit the object, Ill add full stack trace t the exampe

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are creating key yourself in following line:

```
CoverImage.createKeyFromData(imageData)
```

Might be there is collission happening in functions that you have used for two imageData objects which is sometimes causing this issue, if it is just primary key then you can use lot of other approaches to generate a primamry could be simple as setting a UUID.

Cheers !!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by collision ? the datakey has to be a field in the object to allow me to check if an image is already in the database by checking its data, seeing as this as this should be unique I couldn't see an advantage in adding an additional integral based primary key but even if I did I dont think that would solve the underlying problem here.

Comment: @PaulTaylor - By collission I mean if function generates same key, I actually couldnt understand why are you generating this complex key ?

Comment: So that given an arbitary image file I can generate a key based on the data to see if the data has already  been added to the database. If function generate same key that means data is already in the db and I want hibernate to update rather than insert

Answer (score 0):

The primary key must be unique in database, and the CoverImage's primary key is assigned by you by invoking below method. But what if there are two same `imageData` passed in? I am guessing a duplicated primary key would be created, which will cause ConstraintException.

```
   public static String createKeyFromData(byte[] imageData)
{
    try
    {
        String base64key = CharBuffer.wrap(Base64Coder.encode(getImageDataDigest(imageData))).toString();
        return base64key;
    }
    catch (NullPointerException npe)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create filename from sum");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I thought that if I instantiated an object with the same primary key as one that already in the database, then when i called saveOrUpdate() and then commit() that Hibernate would use the fact that it already had a known primary key to identify that this was an object already known to hibernate and hence update the object rather than create a new one. Or am I misunderstanding how hibernate works ?

Comment: Yes. http://www.javabeat.net/2008/09/difference-between-hibernates-saveupdate-and-saveorupdate-methods/

Comment: Besides of what Taylor mentioned, the saveOrUpdate method will also consider if the entity's @version value is null, if so, hibernate will do insert.

Comment: @Taylor Ive read and reread that link and it doesn't explain anything I dont know, or what Im doing wrong.

Comment: @Baggio thankyou if thats true that would explain it, but I can't set the version field myself can I, do you have a reference for this ?

Comment: so to clarify I dont see how the update part of saveOrUpdate() would ever work if constructing the object yourself rather than retrieving it from hibernate yourself, or is that the point ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the reference. As you said above, if you want to do update if the imageData is same, saveOrUpdate() can not help you in this case. You have to search from db to retrive the original data, then set the newly properties into it, and do update. Hope it helps.